# git: freeze/unfreeze working directory according branches

Tags: git, methodology

I am working with git developing a feature, for this I have created a topic/1 branch

The development of this feature has been stopped, as I am waiting for a response
I have a lot of changes in my working directory that are temporary things, that I don't want to save in a commit but I also don't want to lose when I go back to developing  topic/1

How could I switch to a new topic/2 branch, and when I go back to topic/1, return to the working directory as I left it?
I would like to keep the branch display clean and avoid adding temporary commits.

Keep in mind that this situation can happen when doing topic/2. Example I got a response from topic/1, I want to freeze topic/2 and unfreeze topic/1 without losing the changes in the working directory and keeping the commit tree clean

What would be the correct way to approach this workflow?

Comment: Can we know why you ruled out the temporary commit option? `git reset --soft HEAD^` is so fast that the "it takes time" argument would not hold. If there are other reasons not to commit, consider adding a [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for your second branch, it'll allow you to keep the first working tree untouched until you're ready to resume work on it.

Comment: I have not ruled out the option, I am ignorant in git and I am consulting.
´git reset --soft HEAD^´ removes the last commit from the current branch and leaves the changes from that commit in the working directory?

Comment: Yes, it's the command to undo last commit without modifying files, so your changes are kept and ready to be modified/recommitted.

Comment: Don't try to "freeze" anything. Use `git worktree add` to create *more working trees*, with each working tree dedicated to doing work on a particular branch.

Answer (score 1):

git stash should do what you want. It stores any changes that you currently have, without advancing your branch.

`git stash`

Later when you get back to you branch and want to restore the files in your working directory.

`git stash pop`

If you do multiple stashes you need to be a little careful which one you restore but you can find more information on that in the [git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)